# Writing a batch file that moves all files except itself

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm working on a simple cleanup program: it moves all the files that I have in the location to a new folder in that location. However, it moves the batch itself too, which I don't want. Is there a way to (preferably) exclude the batch file itself or at least all batch files?

Comment: The only way to do this IN BATCH that I am aware of is to hide the file before starting the copy, and unhide it after. However, this can be done in PowerShell fairly easily, if that would be acceptable.

Comment: You should, however, be aware that SU.SE is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. For something like this, you should show what you've tried, and describe how it fails. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The title refers to the exception as a filetype (*.bat), while the question is about a specific file (which could be one of many bat files or the only one, maybe even be identifiable as a standard variable).  You don't describe the collection of filenames and types.  For example, might it be practical to use inclusion patterns rather than an exclusion?).  Can you make the question more specific?

Comment: You need to provide examples of this logic... perhaps `IF [%%~A]==[%~NX0] GOTO EOF` or something along those lines... your question lacks much  more needed detail though.`%~NX0` is the substitution for the batch file name itself or `%~FPNX0` is the full explicit path plus the batch file name and the extension.

Answer (score 1):

You don't give us any information on the method(s) used, but you can use [robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx) (bundled with windows), which can accept a list of files to exclude:

So for a hypothetical "foo.bat" (note the example doesn't take into consideration that the current working directory may be different) [[see for example]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file):

```
md .\temp
robocopy .\ .\temp /MOV /XF foo.bat
pause
```

Presumably, you'd want to "parameterize" the destination directory etc. and I *think* you can use a parameter to specify the calling batch file name.